# How to switch tables in model based on users selection

Tags: oop, laravel, eloquent

I get a new dataset every quarter in one table with _yyyymm appended to the end. It's Zipcodes(US)/Postcodes(UK) related.

The user is going to want to select which dataset he wishes to use. So how do I do this without creating multiple Models (one for each dataset)?

I have a postcodes_lookup table with the table names and then my Model needs to use the table they have selected and then produce some results off of that. My lookup table;

```
| id | tablename        | created_on
-------------------------------------
| 1  | postcodes_201502 | 20150201
| 2  | postcodes_201503 | 20150301
| 3  | postcodes_201504 | 20150401
```

My controller has this;

```
$postcodes = Postcodes::postcodes_lookup($id); //id is the postcodes_lookup id.
```

What do I put in my Postcode model so that the model is actually the dataset the user is interested in and not just the lookup table?

This is all in Laravel 5.

Comment: So you want to change tables manually (on users directive)?

Comment: @Kyslik Essentially, yes.

Comment: (Logic): Create new table that is going to list all possible "dataset table names", upon using model in question let it know which table to look in either use GET, session, make sure you define default (maybe in config file) if none above are set. And changing table name is simple just `protected $table = whatevertablenameyouwant;`

Answer (score 0):

I would get the table name with a simple find, then use the table name in the model, something like:

```
public static function lookup($id) {
    $table = self::find($id)->tablename;
    return Db::table($table)->where( ... );
}
```